# copy values in another sheet of excel from a changing value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that searches the nearest value in `H1` in a column then searches the location of that value. Now, I want to select 5 cells above and 5 cells below the range and paste the value into another sheet.

I have a live excel sheet where the means value of `H1` keeps changing. This means the location of the nearest value also keeps changing. The code I have written which correctly pastes the value but it doesn't automatically change when changes are made in `H1`.

So I want that whenever the value in `H1` is changed, the location of the value should also change and the same should be reflected in another cell.

The code below is working fine if the value in `H1` remains the same, but I want that whenever it is changed the value should also change in another sheet.

```
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-4]C[19]"'
```

this formula copy value from other sheet

```
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-4]C[19]"'
```

I want that the rows in the formula should be made dynamic so that they can be changed with a change in the location of another value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but it sounds like you want to place code within Sheet1 in a Worksheet_Change() sub. The code below will execute when H1 is changed in Sheet1, but what's not clear to me is exactly what you want to happen on the other sheet (which I've named "2"). I tried to put something like what you asked, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Hopefully, this will give you a start or help you clarify your question. To test the code, put the code within Sheet1 and change the value of H1. The code will break at the stop line so you can explore what you want to do with the editor.

```
Option Explicit
Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
    stop  'remove this once you've worked out the problems marked ? below
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
    sh.activate
    Set r = sh.Range("B1")
    r.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-4]C[19]" '?
    r.copy                               '?
    sh.paste                             '?
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: its like this in D1 there is some value which is live and keep changing, through formula in H1 location of nearest value can be found. Now i want that value in that location is copied to another sheet in. like when location comes 10 then it should select value of A10 and value should be paste in other sheet and when value of H1 (location) changed to 20 then it should changed to A20 and same should be copy in another sheet

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand what you are saying here. I hope someone else can understand and help you.